# Exec format error while cross compiling erlang 24.0

Tags: erlang, cross-compiling, erlang-otp, powerpc, toolchain

I am trying to cross compile Erlang version 24.0 for 32-bit Linux system using PowerPC toolchain.

While cross compiling this exec format error occur.

This is the error:

```bash
/bin/sh: 1: /home/cdot/Pooja/otp_src_24.0/erts/lib_src/yielding_c_fun/bin/powerpc-unknown-none/yielding_c_fun: Exec format error
make\[4\]: \*\*\* No rule to make target 'powerpc-unknown-none/erl_db_insert_list.ycf.h', needed by 'powerpc-unknown-none/opt/emu/GENERATED'.  Stop.
make\[4\]: Leaving directory '/home/cdot/Pooja/otp_src_24.0/erts/emulator'
make\[3\]: \*\*\* \[/home/Admin/user/otp_src_24.0/make/run_make.mk:35: opt\] Error 2
make\[3\]: Leaving directory '/home/cdot/Pooja/otp_src_24.0/erts/emulator'
make\[2\]: \*\*\* \[Makefile:45: opt\] Error 2
make\[2\]: Leaving directory '/home/Admin/user/otp_src_24.0/erts'
make\[1\]: \*\*\* \[Makefile:54: emu\] Error 2
make\[1\]: Leaving directory '/home/cAdmin/user/otp_src_24.0/erts'
make: \*\*\* \[Makefile:483: emulator\] Error 2
cross-compilation for erlang 24.0
```